# How can i select extra fields and map them to entity via doctrine query builder in symfony?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have two entities: Category and Product. Category entity has not link to Product `(protected $products // ArrayColection)`. I need to calculate total amount of product prices inside each category, and i need to do it ONLY IN SINGLE request via query builder.

Can i do something like this:

```
$categories = $categoryRepository->createQueryBuilder('c')->join('AppBundle:Product', 'p')->addSelect('SUM(p.price) as c.totalPrice')->addGroupBy('c.id')->getQuery()->getResults();
```

And then map attribute `totalPrice` to entity, to have access to it somehow like this:

```
$categories->get(0)->totalAmount
```

I CAN'T build extra query, and i CAN'T add relationsip field to Category ($products) to calculte totalSum in entity method by adding price of each product. I should done it only with single query...

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is possible with Doctrine > 2.4

Check out their docs for more details on joins: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Meanwhile - this is what should work for you:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Product', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.category = c.id')
            ->select('SUM(p.price) as totalPrice')
            ->groupBy('c.id');
```

Note how we use the leftJoin method parameters - this is what allows you to run the query despite there is no relation between tables.

Hope that works for you

Comment: But how i can map totalPrice to Category object? I want something like this `$query = ...; $recordset = $query->getQuery()->getResults();`

Comment: `foreach ($recordset as $category) {                                                                                                                       $category->getTotalAmount() /* or */ $category->totalAmount;                             }`

Comment: The easiest way would be adding a non-mapped property to the category entity called totalAmount. Then, in the category repository you would run the above query along with the $this->findAll(). The last step would be iterating over categories and running $category->setTotalAmount() on each. Will describe this in my answer in a few.